# Create a do not forget list app on google home

Tags: reminders, google-home

Is it possible to create the following:

Me:"Hey Google, I'm leaving!"
Home:"Don't forget your keys, wallet & phone. Have a great day!"

Better yet:

M: "Hey Google, add "watch" to the "I'm Leaving" list.
H: "Ok. I have added "watch" to the "I'm Leaving" list.

Really cool:

M: "Hey Google, add "portfolio" to the "I'm Leaving" list.
H: "Ok. I will add "portfolio" to the "I'm Leaving" list. Would you like to add this to the list one time, or always?
M: "One time."
H: Ok. "Portfolio" will be mentioned in your next request of the "I'm leaving" list. It will then be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Yes you can](https://developers.google.com/actions/).

Details are left as an exercise to the reader.